# Add <script> to the bottom of a html file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a bunch of HTML files, and I need to add `<script src="ga.js"></script>` before each search instance of "`</body></html>`".

How would I add that to the bottom of all these files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If they're actually on the same line, you can do it pretty trivially with `sed`:

```
$ sed -i '/<\/body><\/html>/ i <script src="ga.js"></script>' *.html
```

That finds all html files in the current directory (`*.html`), searches for `</body></html>` (`/.../`), and inserts (`i`) the script tag before it, writing the changes back to the same file (`-i`)

Comment: You can probably drop the search for `<\/html>`. Even if it turns up on another line, the important part is that this ends up before the closing body tag.